# json_query uses contains to search item within another list failed

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have list of samples, and i want to select the item whose type is in the wanted_list.

```
- name: Get item based on anther list
  vars: 
    samples:
      - { item: 10, type: sample-1 },
      - { item: 20, type: sample-11 },
      - { item: 30, type: sample-2 }
    wanted_list: [ sample-11, sample-2 ]
    query: "[?contains('{{wanted_list|to_json}}', type)]"
  debug:
    var: samples | json_query(query)
```

Result:

```
TASK: Get item based on anther list
ok: [localhost] => {
    "samples|json_query(query)": [
        {
            "item": 10,
            "type": "sample-1"
        },
        {
            "item": 20,
            "type": "sample-11"
        },
        {
            "item": 30,
            "type": "sample-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i expected is it will only return item 20 and 30. But it actually return all 3. It looks like sample-1 match part of the list item sample-11.

But based on JMESPath doc [contains](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains):

> boolean contains(array|string $subject, any $search)
>
> If $subject is an array, this function returns true if one of the elements in the array
> is equal to the provided $search value.

So sample-1 is not equal to sample-11 and then it should not be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [the backtick in order to quote literal JSON](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) like that, since the [single quote is just for strings](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals)

```yaml
  - name: Get item based on anther list
    vars: 
      samples:
        - { item: 10, type: sample-1 }
        - { item: 20, type: sample-11 }
        - { item: 30, type: sample-2 }
      wanted_list: [ sample-11, sample-2 ]
      query: "[?contains(`{{ wanted_list | to_json }}`, type)]"
    debug:
      msg: '{{ samples | json_query(query) }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The filters [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) and [*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) do the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ samples|selectattr('type', 'in', wanted_list)|
                         map(attribute='item')|
                         list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: [20, 30]
```

---

Fix the syntax of the list *samples* and remove the commas at the end of the lines

```yaml
  vars: 
    samples:
      - {item: 10, type: sample-1}
      - {item: 20, type: sample-11}
      - {item: 30, type: sample-2}
```